# How to create a form add button

Tags: javascript, html, web, aframe

There is a code to add text to the iframe. How to add a button to create new fields for text

```js
$("#text1").click(function(e) {
  var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  document.getElementById("output").setAttribute("text", "value", x);
  return false;
});
```

```css
form {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>

<form name="myForm" href="" onsubmit="text">
  id: <input type="number" value="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br><br>
  <input id="text1" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>

<a-scene background="color: black">
  <a-entity id="output" text="value: output; align: center;" position="0 1.6 -0.5"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: The same way you set the attributes by a button click. Instead of changing an attribute with setAttribute(), create a new text field and insert it at the correct location. So you either create the HTML string and insert that with innerHTML or you create actual nodes to appendChild() somewhere.

Comment: At first [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), then [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Answer (score 1):

1) Use `createElement()` to create a new element.

```
let newEl = document.createElement('a-entity')
```

2) Throw it inside a "container" using `container.appendChild(newEl)`

The container could be a simple parent element:

```
<a-entity id='textContainer'>
</a-entity>
```

---

On `click`, create the element, set the properties, and append it to the container:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("textContainer");
// set the position below the last element
var position = new THREE.Vector3(0, wrapper.children.length * -0.05, 0);

var newText = document.createElement('a-entity')
newText.setAttribute('position', position)
newText.setAttribute("text", {
  "color": "white",
  "align": "center",
  "value": document.querySelector('#fname').value
})
wrapper.appendChild(newText)
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9yr85b31/1/).